# Are there any softwares on Windows to measure bluetooth signal strength?

Tags: windows, windows-7, bluetooth, signal, signal-strength

I was wondering if there are any softwares on windows that can measure the signal strength of the connected bluetooth device?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyBluez to interact with the Bluetooth stack.  They have example code that does inquiry scan and prints RSSI

http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py